# Three.js :geometric shapes from the same point of view

Tags: javascript, geometry, three.js

I want create a picture of a number of geometric shapes. My problem is that I need that all of them will be visible from the same point of view - i.e. I dont need the real 3d scene, but, instead, a number of small shape pictures one near another.

How can i do it with Three.js?

I know how to draw each of my shapes in the required view in the middle of the screen, but I do not know how create a number of shapes inside specific div one after another
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is with `renderer.setViewport()` and multiple cameras. Here is the pattern:

```
renderer.setViewport( 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
renderer.render( scene, camera1 );

renderer.setViewport( SCREEN_WIDTH/2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
renderer.render( scene, camera2 );
```

This approach does not require separate div's.

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_camera.html

Another approach is to use multiple divs as in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CLEYk/ .

three.js r.53

Comment: The second one looks exactly what I need!